# Skill based resume - what tense?

Tags: resume

In a 1 page skill based resume, what tense should I use? For example, under Marketing, I've listed 5 skills - 3 were used in the past whereas 2 are being utilitized in my current job.

Is mixing past & present (though accurate) wise?

Answer (score 1):

Are they your current skills? For instance, if I was a mad soup chef in the past and am currently a master steak chef but haven't cooked soup in years and if asked too was unable too then no don't list it. However, if you HAVE the skills and are able to do them then list them.

Don't list anything in your resume you are uncomfortable being asked about or performing or being tested on, if you are and they are beneficial skills to the job you are looking for then yes, by all means list them.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of what verb tense to use when listing skills.

Comment: Nor does it ask for 'verb tense'

Comment: It specifically asks for what tense to list skills in.  What other meaning of tense would fit in this context?

Comment: Kid, once you have lived and worked with people of all nationalities and have actually left the country once in your life to work somewhere other than your comfort zone and have some actual experience in the real world you'll understand. Until then, answer the question in the way you think fit instead of adding nothing of value by tagging into someone elses.

Comment: I left my home country to be an English teacher for over 7 years.  I have had to answer dozens of this sort of question in adult English classes.  This is clearly a "What is the appropriate grammar in this situation?" question.

Comment: Your grammar/wordage/run on sentences are hard to read in that response, I believe you mean "I left my home country to be an English teacher and taught for more than 7 years. I have answered dozens of questions like this all while teaching in my adult English classes".

Then you should know that the way people translate the word 'tense' from their perceptive language to English is broad and colorful, makes me wonder why you are so 'hiccuped' on this response.

Comment: People not bothering to actually read questions before answering makes me tense.

Comment: Well if you notice, the OP is mentioning 'past, present' i.e. tense could easily be 'past tense, present tense' which is a grammatical version of tense, as an "english teacher" you should of picked up on that maybe your tense  because your projecting the fact that you didn't read the question and felt the need to over analyze answers without a basis.

Comment: "'past tense, present tense' " would be examples of verb tenses.  If you had provided an answer to which of these two tenses to use then you would have answered the OPs question.  "However, if you HAVE the skills and are able to do them then list them" is almost an answer but does not tell the OP in what tense to list them.  I think you should expand your answer, the tension is killing me.

Comment: It does answer that... tense doesn't matter, that is the answer - your skills on your resume should dictate your skills in real life if you did it in the past or present and you can't do it, don't list it and vice versa. You're too caught up in specifics instead of having an answer that helps the underlying issue. Don't bandage things, fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Skill based resume - what tense?

While the strength of a skill may fade with time, generally skills don't disappear completely - you either have the skill or you don't. It doesn't matter if you currently use that skill or not.

In my experience, skill-based resumes are written in the present tense.

If you find yourself agonizing over a skill that was used so long in the past you wouldn't know how to do it any longer, that's a sign that you should leave it off your resume.

Answer (score -1):

You are going into excessive detail. If you used skills several years ago, your skills are somewhat rusty but you can get them back with a minimum of practice, simply list them as current skills - By the way, the only skills that matter are current skills.

Don't clutter your resume with obsolete skills and skills that no longer have any relevance to anyone anymore.